# Publishing site template for Site Collection

Tags: 2010, site-template

In SP 2010, The default Publishing Portal template comes with publishing workflow activated. How can I create a new site collection which is equivalent to "Publishing Site" (without workflow)?

[image]

I know that there is option to create a site with/without workflow. I am looking for Site Collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you are not SharePoint Developer for Custome Site collection template usage, you can disable **Publishing Approval Workflow** feature of Publishing template.

You can do the following steps:

1. Open your new Publishing site.
2. Click **Site Actions** > **Site Settings** > **Site collection features** (under **Site Collection Administrator**)
3. Deactivate Publishing Approval Workflow feature.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

I know only one way - create site collection by code, where you can set site code.
How to get code of all templates: http://toreinarsolli.wordpress.com/2010/10/21/sharepoint-2010-using-custom-site-template-in-code/